# How to directly access to what's in VARIANT variables in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, variant

My program uses an external ocx library and receives data through it. The code below shows how it works.

```
    VARIANT    varArrItem, varArrData;

    ocx_instance.GetItemArr(real, &varArrItem);      // the library provides GetItemArr
                                                     // 1) receives data 
    long lLBound, lUBound;
    VARIANT varItem, varData;

    long index[2];
    index[0] = 0;
    index[1] = 0;

    COleSafeArray* pSafeItemArr = (COleSafeArray*)&varArrItem;    // 2) casts varArrItem to COleSafeArray
    CString strItem;
    CStringArray arrItem;

    pSafeItemArr->GetLBound(1, &lLBound);
    pSafeItemArr->GetUBound(1, &lUBound);

    int nItemCnt = (lUBound - lLBound + 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < nItemCnt; i++)
    {
        index[0] = i;
        VariantInit(&varItem);

        pSafeItemArr->GetElement(index, (void *)&varItem);    // 3) gets its values using GetElement
        strItem = varItem.bstrVal;
        arrItem.Add(strItem);

        VariantClear(&varItem);
    }
```

A big problem of the program is that this code is run whenever new data arrives, which is quite often, and it consumes a lot of resources. So, I'd like to simplify the code and get just contents of `varArrItem`, as strings or an array of structs of strings, for example.

`varArrItem.vt` gives me 8204 and it's said that it consists of `8192(VT_ARRAY)` and `12(VT_VARIANT)`. I'm stuck here and don't know what to do after this. How can I simply get what's in them? Is it possible to access to them without using COleSafeArray?

Comment: Your `varArrData` appears to contain a VT_ARRAY|VT_VARIANT variant type, which means its a SAFEARRAY of VARIANT. Sooner or later a copy is going to come into play unless you retool your container to hold raw BSTR (or CComBSTR via detatch+attach), "steal" the VT_BSTR from each item, and shove it into your retooled container. Frankly  I don't see it worth the trouble. Two things, btw: (1) You really should init that varArritem before sending it to the GetItemArr instance, and (2), That cast is hideous, There are ways to "properly" rehome ownsership of that SAFEARRAY into a COleSafeArray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't NEED to use `COleSafeArray`, it is just a wrapper for convenience. You could just extract the `SAFEARRAY*` pointer directly from `varArrItem` and then use the SafeArray APIs directly: `SafeArrayGet(L|U)Bound()`, `SafeArrayGetElement()`, etc, though if performance is important then consider using `SafeArrayAccessData()` to access the `VARIANT[]` array directly, and thus its `BSTR` pointers. The less copying of data you do, the faster the code will run. The only copy of data this code actually needs to make is the assignment of the initial `VARIANT` and each `CString` you add to the `CStringArray`:

```cpp
VARIANT varArray;
ocx_instance.GetItemArr(real, &varArray);

LPSAFEARRAY psa = varArrar.parray;

LONG lLBound, lUBound;
SafeArrayGetLBound(psa, 1, &lLBound);
SafeArrayGetUBound(psa, 1, &lUBound); 

CStringArray arrItem;

VARIANT *varArrayData;
if (SUCCEEDED(SafeArrayAccessData(psa, (void**) &varArrayData)))
{
    int nItemCnt = (lUBound - lLBound + 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < nItemCnt; i++)
    {
        CString strItem = varArrayData[i].bstrVal;
        arrItem.Add(strItem);
    }

    SafeArrayUnaccessData(psa);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and example code! Would it be possible to get the content of ```varArrayData``` without for loop or adding each value to ```arrItem``` seperately? I tried casting the array like: ```string arr_data = *((string*)&varArrayData);```, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @maynull no, that will not work. You have a SAFEARRAY of VARIANTs containing BSTRs. BSTR is itself a pointer, so you need to access the strings individually